# Является ли запись в переменную атомарной операцией?

Tags: c, c++

Может ли выражение

```
variable = value;
```

быть прервано "внутри"? То есть, может ли во время (после начала, но еще до конца) записи в переменную произойти другая запись в эту же переменную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае, выражение

```
variable = value;
```

может быть прервано "внутри". Если variable - это переменная сложного типа, например, struct, то для реального присваивания понадобится несколько машинных операций и после каждой операции может вклиниться поток более высокого приоритета. Про атомарность можно говорить только для правильно выровненных переменных размером не больше машинного слова.

Comment: Точно, я про выравнивание забыл.

Comment: На самом деле, даже если переменная типа int не выравнена, то её пересылка или присваивание всё равно будет элементарной операцией и будет выполняться одной командой процессора. Только время выполнения команды будет больше, чем при операции с выровненной переменной. А одна команда процессора - всегда атомарная операция.

Answer (score 2):

В С++, для переменных тип которых не `std::atomic<T>`, во время выполнения выражения `variable = value` запись и чтение этой переменной из других потоков невозможна,
т.к. иначе произошла бы гонка данных (data race), а в правильной программе на С++ гонок быть не может (иначе будет неопределенное поведение, UB).

Для переменных с типом `std::atomic<T>` запись атомарна по определению атомарности в С++.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно пометить переменную как `volatile`. Переменная должна располагаться по выровненному адресу. (кратно машинному слову)

Необходимо чтобы переменная была чем-то, что влелзает в регистр: целое, указатель, символ.

В любом случае лучше всегда посмотреть асмовый вывод, чтобы убедиться в этом. (`gcc -S`)

Comment: Если переменная влезает в регистр, то volatile тут вообще ни при чём и без него можно спокойно обойтись, если не нужен ИМЕННО volatile.

Comment: volatile указывает компилятору, что переменная может быть изменена неочевидным для него способом и остерегает от оптимизаций, так?

Comment: Точно. Но это не меняет погоды в связи атомарностью\неатомарностью. Это влияет совсем на другое. Вы можете спокойно выкинуть volatile и не испортить этим атомарность. Это повлияет только на своевременную доступность переменной другим потокам. Но в любом случае они получат либо старую, либо новую версию.

Comment: Вы уверены что после того как выкинете volatile, компилятор не выкинет вашу переменную в целях оптимизации, или оставит ее новое значение регистре до поры до времени?

Comment: Может и оставит. Но вопрос-то был не о том ;)

Comment: Извините за снобизм, но без volatile может и не быть операции присваивания. А вопрос наверно задан в контексте много поточного программирования, думаю не стоит провоцировать трудно уловимые ошибки.

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, если *value* это константа, а *variable* обьявлена как *volatile*, то в середину этой операции другой поток не вклинится.

Comment: Запросто можно вклиниться при присвоении чего-то, что не влезает в регистр. Например, 64битное целое на 32битном процессоре.

Answer (score -1):

Если доступ к переменной происходит как к единому целому(тоесть запись например дворда или состояния fpu), то операция атомарна. Если переменная сложная, то необходима синхронизация. Тоесть в простейшем случае переменная дворд, а вы обращаеттесь к ней как к байту. Хардварно решается использование префикса Lock. Програмно обсуждать смысла нет, так как это скрипта проблемы.